# Where does LXRandr save its display configurations?

Tags: settings, lxde, display-manager, lxrandr

It looks like LXRandr can save configurations.

[image]

But where are they saved and in what form?

(I was thinking about activating them by shortkey.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To know what has changed in the home folder:

```
find ~/ -mmin -5 -type f
```

You can change 5 to a smaller number if you wish.

In this way, after saving configuration in LXRandr and running this command, the last change recorded is in `~/.config/autostart/lxrandr-autostart.desktop`. That's it.

To open that:

```
gedit ~/.config/autostart/lxrandr-autostart.desktop
```

It contains something like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=LXRandR autostart
Comment=Start xrandr with settings done in LXRandR
Exec=xrandr --output LVDS --mode 1680x1050 --rate 60.1 --output VGA-0 --off
OnlyShowIn=LXDE
```

It says that it just starts "xrandr with settings done in LXRandR". It's an `xrandr` configuration. In the example the external display is connected by VGA but shut down.

(To activate that configuration by a keybind, the line to be used is the one after `Exec=`. It will vary according to the active display settings at the moment when LXRandr saved them. Many separate configurations can be saved in this way to be used with different keybinds; but after saving with LXRandr the file `lxrandr-autostart.desktop` is overwritten.)

Comment: the line gave me a lot more answers (many mozilla related as i am in it): but the first might be the one i want: `~/.config/autostart/lxrandr-autostart.desktop`. i'll see what is to be done with that

Comment: True, but with a little precaution, you can make sure that other entries don't pollute the output.