# How can I make xrandr customization permanent in Lubuntu 14.04?

Tags: lubuntu, xrandr

I used xrand to generate `xrandr --output LVDS-1 --mode 1366x768 --pos 1920x0 --rotate normal --output HDMI-1 --off --output VGA-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal` command.

xrandr proposed saving it in ~/.screenlayout/ folder, and it is not automatically used on logging in.

Running it from terminal mostly works, but display of workspaces in taskbar is horizontally squashed.

Adding it to autostart (via ~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart) has no effect whatsoever.

Comment: Lubuntu 14.10 reached end-of-life, it's an old release.

Comment: @user300458 Given that I confirmed that it works both in .10 and .04. As .04 is still supported unlike .10 I retitled this submission. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove [LXRandR configuration file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259785/where-does-lxrandr-save-its-display-configurations).

Create a ~/.xprofile (ensure that it is executable) with xrandr command as content. Solution was found via https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#By_Session_with_.xprofile

With external monitor unavailable it will cause message to appear and it will not cause further problems.